# how do you map classes to an array which was a HTMLcollection earlier

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking, IF the  with #CNC_Mach_btn contains an .active class then the  tags with .CNC_Machinery class in it should receive a .show class, this part works.

But I also want to remove the .show class on  tags without a .CNC_Machinery class.

I changed the NodeLists to arrays and then iterate through tehm and then appended .s

I tried the JS idea "else if (!CNC_Mach_btn.classList.contains("active")) {
" ! from [here](https://techstacker.com/posts/cXTuMZ2XutfH36SYc/vanilla-javascript-how-to-check-if-a-class-exists-practical)
but that didn't work.

HTML & PHP:

JS:

```
      //gets all category buttons
      // this returns a !!!nodeList!!!!
      let category_btn = document.querySelectorAll('.category-button');
      // gets the button with #CNC_Machining_button for click EventListener
      // this returns a !!!HTMLCollection!!!!
      let CNC_Mach_btn = document.getElementById("CNC_Machining_button");
      //gets anchor tags where the .images class is (all <a> have an image class)
      // this returns a !!!nodeList!!!!

      let Images_Class_In_Anchor_Tag = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
      //transforming nodeList into an array
      const All_Images_Class_MakeArray = Array.from(Images_Class_In_Anchor_Tag);
      //gets .CNC_Machinery classes from anchor tags where also .images class is located
      // this returns a !!!NodeList!!!!
      let CNC_Machining_Class_In_AnchorTag = document.querySelectorAll(".CNC_Machinery");
      //transforming nodeList into an array
      const CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray = Array.from(CNC_Machining_Class_In_AnchorTag);



    CNC_Mach_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

       if (CNC_Mach_btn.classList.contains("active")) {
        CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray.forEach(el => el.classList.add("show"));  
        if (!All_Images_Class_MakeArray.forEach(el => el.classList.contains("CNC_Machinery"))) {
        CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("show"));
        }
      }
    });
```

HTML & PHP:

```
<section class="gallery-links">
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="product-gallery-title">Product Gallery</h2>

  <div class="gallery-container">
    <?php
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY orderGallery DESC';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
      echo 'SQL statement failed!';
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //what's echoed out by the database

        echo '  <a class="images '.$row["image_category"].'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                </div>
                </a>';
      }
    }


    ?>  

  </div>
```

Expected Result: .show should be added to anchor tag which contains .CNC_Machinery

Actual Result: .show is not added and removed to anchor tag which contains .CNC_Machinery

Comment: for (i = 0; i < CNC_Mach_btn.length; i++) - should this be looping CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray

Comment: 3 things. 1) `CNC_Mach_btn` is an `HtmlElement`, you don't need to loop it. `.length` doesn't exist so you'll never enter the first loop.  2) You don't need to make an array with the `nodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` since it contains the property `.length`. It even has the `.forEach()` method. 3) When adding the class, you're adding it on the node list, which would throw an error if your code reached there. Use your index before using `.classList`: `CNC_Machining_Class_In_AnchorTag[i].classList.add("show");
`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is actually mostly correct, with one exception: your are trying to access the `.classList` of an array of nodes, that does not work. Instead, you simply loop through the array of nodes and then access the classList for each individual node:

```
CNC_Mach_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (CNC_Mach_btn.classList.contains("active")) {
    CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.add("show");
    });
  }
});
```

Update: since you are using ES6, you can also use arrow functions to make your code a little more concise:

```
CNC_Mach_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (CNC_Mach_btn.classList.contains("active")) {
    CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray.forEach(el => el.classList.add("show"));
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you Terry, this really helped. I need to look deeper into the rules and keep on learning.

Comment: @Dan No problen :) I see that you're using ES6 (based on your use of `Array.from`), and will update my answer for another improvement.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I noticed when I implemented the code that a ')' was missing. ;)=

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the heads up, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `forEach` method of `NodeList` after fetching all the elements with class `CNC_Machinery`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.CNC_Machinery').forEach(e => {
  e.classList.add('show');
});
```

```css
.show {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="CNC_Machinery">Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<p class="CNC_Machinery">P 1</p>
```